# Running multiple workers in docker in different containers

Tags: docker, nestjs, bull

I want to have a nestjs docker app with nestjs/bull which contains 1 web container, 1 redis container and 2 workers - one for slow jobs and one for fast jobs. But whatever I do I get errors - sometimes the workers exit with code 0 on start, other solutions don't give me anything when I make a request or both containers can handle the same worker. I want specific container to handle specific worker.

my docker compose has:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    hostname: my-web-container

  worker-one:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/workers/worker-one/worker-one.dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
    hostname: my-slow-container
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_QUEUE_NAME: one

  
  worker-two:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/workers/worker-two/worker-two.dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
    hostname: my-fast-container
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_QUEUE_NAME: fast # or any other unique name you choose

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

The one worker looks like this(the other is similiar):

```
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Job } from 'bull';

@Processor('one')
export class WorkerOne{
  @Process('slow-job')
  async handleJob(job: Job<unknown>): Promise<void> {
    console.log(`Processing slow-job, data: ${JSON.stringify(job.data)}`);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // simulate slow processing
    console.log(`Slow-job done!`);
  }
}
```

The one.docker.dockerfile contains:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:one"]
```

The service has:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Queue } from 'bull';

@Injectable()
export class JobService {
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('one') private readonly oneQueue: Queue,
    @InjectQueue('two') private readonly twoQueue: Queue,
  ) {}

  async addJob(data: any): Promise<void> {
    if (data.name === 'userOne') {
      console.log('slower');
      await this.oneQueue.add('slow-job', data);
    } else {
      console.log('faster');
      await this.twoQueue.add('fast-job', data);
    }
  }
}
```

and the workers.module.ts(Which is imported in app.module.ts has:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { JobController } from './controllers/job.controller';
import { JobService } from './services/job.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'redis',
        port: 6379,
      },
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueue(
      {
        name: 'one',
      },
      {
        name: 'two',
      },
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [JobController],
  providers: [JobService],
})
export class WorkersModule {}
```

in the package.json I have:

```
"start:one": "node dist/main slow",
```

I also tried changing package.json start:one to go to the specific worker path but doesn't do the trick.
Any ideas how to fix this?